# Configuring nginx to use ingress authentication by default on GKE?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've been trying to set up ingress authentication for an nginx server running on GKE, per [these instructions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/). I want to always require auth by default instead of just "foo.bar.com", so the ingress config in my manifest looks like this instead:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-with-auth
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: 'Authentication Required - foo'
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
---
```

When I use `kubectl create -f` to deploy, everything spins up properly and the ingress IP displays the default nginx page as expected, but it doesn't ask for auth credentials at all. Why not?

Comment: GKE have it own `Ingress`. If you want to `Nginx Ingress Controller` on GKE you must enforce it by using annotation: `annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`.
You want to authengicate using `Nginx Ingress` or `GKE Ingress`?

Comment: Hi @PjoterS. This may seem ignorant, but what is the difference between the two? Where can I read about use cases of each? I haven't had a lot of luck finding resources that clearly illustrate the difference between the two.

Comment: You can find some details [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke). In short, if you are using GKE Ingress, you need to have service as `NodePort`. If you want to use Nginx Ingress you must deploy Nginx Ingress Controller (best using Helm). Nginx have more features and services can be type `ClusterIP` or `NodePort`.

Comment: I see, thank you for the info! I'd like to use GKE ingress. My service is already type NodePort, so I'm not sure what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will be not able to use `Ingress authentication` using default [GKE Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)

Link to the docs you have provided is for `Nginx Ingress Controller` which means you would need to use `Nginx Ingress` not `GKE Ingress`.

As I mentioned in comments, GKE as Default ingress is using Ingress provided by GCE. You can check [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) tutorial with comparision `Nginx Ingress Controller` and `GKE Ingress`

> On Google Kubernetes Engine, if no annotation is defined under the metadata section, the Ingress Resource uses the GCP GCLB L7 load balancer to serve traffic. This method can also be forced by setting the annotation's value to gce as shown below:

`annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce`

If you would like to use `Nginx Ingress` on `GKE` you should do at least 2 things:

**1**. Deploy `Nginx Ingress Controller`

**a**.) Using Helm

`$ helm install ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.publishService.enabled=true`

If you are curious why you need specify this flag you can check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520313/gke-ingress-resource-with-nginx-load-balancer-shows-strange-ip/).

**b**.) Using [Official docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke).

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
  
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

**2**. Specify that you want to use `Nginx Ingress`.

You can do it by using annotation:

```
annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

As example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: 'Authentication Required - foo'
...
```

Very similar situation is with [Nginx Ingress Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/). As `GKE Ingres`s is not supporting this `Nginx` feature you would also need to deploy `Nginx Ingress`, add `annotation` to use it and configure it properly.

Hope it cleared a bit. If you would still have issue, let me know in comments.